# order by date limit to one and group by sub id

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

```
$r=mysql_query("
(
SELECT * 
FROM commentsvv AS dt  
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,'$dset')>0
  AND  id2='$uid'
  AND  status_id2='0'
ORDER BY datetimep DESC LIMIT 1)

UNION

(
SELECT * 
FROM commentsvv AS dt
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id2,'$dsetv')>0
  AND id='$uid'
  AND status_id='0'
ORDER BY datetimep DESC LIMIT 1)
");
```

sorry I have no clue how to properly format that query. need to read about that, so the thing in there is it is retrieving one result overall for id and for id2. I would want to retrieve one result for each member in `$dset` or `$dsetv` if it were available, meaning group by id in the first query, in the second group by id2 and order by datetimep desc limit 1. Can't get it going.

Comment: You should use same field names when using `UNION` clause.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is sub-query, you don't need other half of query, and how can you group something or why do you want to group if you are just requesting one record?
w3schools.org

Comment: I want to have one record for each id and id2 (many in total) ordered by timestamp

Comment: I can see above that you are calling data just from one table, it'll be automatically grouped, I hope id is unique (it was suppose to be) we only group things that aren't genuine, for example I've list of friends I can group them by city, or state, why do i need to group them by id. or you can give me two records as example and i'll send you the query you need, at most i can do

Comment: grouping by id and id2 because I want to display only one result for each user, it is a conversations table, id is the id of user a, and id2 is the id of user b, I want to display last conversation row in between the two users where the logged in user is either placed as id (sender) or id2 (receiver)

Comment: oh ok, now i get it, you need to make two queries, Make one query for id1 and another for for id2. or if you want to dispay comments as conversation you can put (where id =1 or id =2) in just one query. Again if it doesn't solve your problem please let me see atleast two records of you file, else don't expect any answers, thanks.